# How do I switch the order of integration for this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> I am unable to find the limits of this integral: $$\int_{x=0}^{2} \int_{y=x/2}^{1} 2xy^2 dydx$$

When it is switched. I tried to find the value of $x$ in the inner integral when $y = 1$ and when $y = x/2$, which gives me $2x$ and $x^3/3$, but for the outer integral when substituted will definitely have a lingering $ y$ value. This makes my new expression expressed in terms of $y$, which is definitely not the same as the original expression.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The domain of the double integral is the triangle of vertices $(0,0)$, $(2,1)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: How do you know it's a triangle from the equation $xy^2$? Is there a way I could visualize this?

Comment: From the integral limits, the domain is the union of the vertical segments with end points $(x,x/2)$ and $(x,1)$ for $x\in [0,2]$. Make a drawing. The integrand $2xy^2$ is not involved in the determination of the domain.

Comment: @user102938475 The domain is not obtained from $xy^2$. It is obtained from $0\le x\le2,\frac{x}{2}\le y\le1$.

Comment: From my drawing, i get that y is between 0 and 1 and x is between 2 and 0. But i need to let x to be between x=2y and x=0 to get the correct answer. Why does the inner integral have an expression as the limits when the bounds of the diagram I draw have concrete values (the triangle vertices).

Comment: As $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$, you should take the union of the segments (of VARIABLE size) of end points $(0,y)$ to $(2y,y)$. If you take the union of the segments (of FIXED size) of end points $(0,y)$ to $(2,y)$ you will obtain the rectangle $[0,2]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. I now have a hypothesis that goes like this: for the x domain from 0 to 2, we make it into 0 to 2y because the inner integral needs to be expressed as a fn of y. Then the outer integral must be a concrete value so we let y be from 0 to 1 as per the vertices of the triangle. I am confused.

Comment: No, it's correct, and it is consistent with what I told you. Think about it... and draw!

Answer (score 0):

I find that the easiest way to switch the order of integration is to sketch the region of integration (that is, sketch the region bounded by $x=0$, $x=2$, $y=x/2$ and $y=1$).  Then you know you want $y$ to be the outer integral which means your $y$ bounds must be constant, so, using your sketch, determine what the smallest and largest values of $y$ are.  Next, for any $y$ value, determine the bounds on $x$ (which will generally now depend on $y$).

Comment: I'm quite stuck at this as well. For the region, am I supposed to draw the graph of $xy^2$? How should i draw this? Let some $z = xy^2$?

Comment: You don't want the graph of $xy^2$.  You  want to sketch the region over which you will be integrating, which is given by $$x/2 \leq y \leq 1 \quad\text{and}\quad 0\leq x \leq 2$$.  As Robert pointed out above, draw each of the bounds and determine the shape of the region.